# Нужна ли многопоточность, чтобы показывать прогресс долговыполняющейся функции

Tags: python, python-2.x

У меня есть функция выполняющая полезную нагрузку, выполняется она относительно долго ( 20 - 40 сек). В этот момент пользователь должен что-то получать на экран, например, вывод символа #, символизирующий прогресс задачи. Иначе пользователь может подумать, что программа повисла.

Предполагаю, текущую задачу нужно решать используя многопоточность? Какие наиболее эффективные решения имеет эта задача?

Comment: Ну тот же символ # можно печатать и из одного потока

Comment: для отрисовки прогресса, есть модуль progressbar.

Comment: Содержит ли функция внутренний цикл, которым прогресс можно мерять (больше итераций, ближе к завершению)? Связанный вопрос:[Text Progress Bar in the Console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3173320/4279)

Comment: Я бы посмотрел в сторону асинхронных решений этого вопроса.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173320/text-progress-bar-in-the-console

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Предполагаю, текущую задачу нужно решать используя многопоточность?

Совсем не обязательно, например, [`urllib.urlretrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) принимает `reporthook(blocknum, blocksize, totalsize)` функцию обратного вызова в качестве аргумента, которая вызывается после каждого скачивания очередного блока данных. Вот [пример кода, демонстрирующий различные варианты реализации reporthook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13895723/4279), которые показывают прогресс скачивания файла в том же потоке или используя отдельный поток в консоли или GUI.

Если затяжная функция не предоставляет информации, когда она завершится, то можно запустить её в отдельном потоке и, к примеру, печатать текущее время, чтобы показать что программа жива (сама функция может висеть при этом):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
import threading
import time

def long_function(): 
    time.sleep(100) # здесь некий долгий непрозрачный код

t = threading.Thread(target=long_function)
t.start()
while t.is_alive(): # пока функция выполняется
     t.join(1)      # ждём секунду пока поток завершится
     sys.stderr.write('\r' + time.ctime()) # обновляем время
```

Многие терминалы поддерживают `'\r'` ([символ возврата каретки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)) — курсор перемещается в начало строки при выводе этого символа (на Windows может потребоваться [`colorama` библиотека](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama)).

В качестве менее навязчивой альтернативы, можно показывать небольшую односимвольную анимацию с помощью `'\b'` ([возврат на шаг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B)), который перемещает позицию печати на один символ назад:

```
import itertools

t = threading.Thread(target=long_function)
t.start()
for c in itertools.cycle('/|\-'):
    if not t.is_alive():
        break
    t.join(.3)
    sys.stderr.write('\b' + c)
```

Чтобы не изобретать велосипед, можно готовую библиотеку использовать такую как [`tqdm` (читается как «такадум»)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26394657/4279).

Answer (score 7):

```
import time
import threading


def mprint(fn):
    '''вывод символа #, символизирующий прогресс задачи'''
    print('start mprint')

    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        t = threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.start()  # Предполагаю, текущую задачу нужно решать используя многопоточность
        # t.join() # Иначе пользователь может подумать, что программа повисла
        while t.is_alive():
            print('# В этот момент пользователь должен что-то получать на экран')
            time.sleep(1)

        print('stop mprint')
    return wrap


# @mprint
def worker(wait=1):
    '''У меня есть функция выполняющая полезную нагрузку'''
    print('start worker')
    for w in range(wait):
        print('выполняется она относительно долго')
        time.sleep(1)
    print('stop worker')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # worker(wait=3)
    mprint(worker)(wait=3)
```

out:

```
start mprint
start worker
выполняется она относительно долго
# В этот момент пользователь должен что-то получать на экран
# В этот момент пользователь должен что-то получать на экран
выполняется она относительно долго
# В этот момент пользователь должен что-то получать на экран
выполняется она относительно долго
# В этот момент пользователь должен что-то получать на экран
stop worker
stop mprint
```