# Не работает цикл из itertools.cycle() использующий \b в PyCharm

Tags: python, циклы, pycharm

По задумке этим циклом должна крутиться вертушка, но этого не происходит. Использую Python версии 3.5, код запускаю в PyCharm CE, операционка - Mac OSX. Код привел ниже:

```
import itertools
import time

def loop():
    for c in itertools.cycle('-/|\\'):
        print(c + '\b', flush=True, end='')
        time.sleep(0.3)
loop()
```

Comment: Во-первых укажите, что именно происходит, во-вторых скорее всего консоль, встроенная в PyCharm не поддерживает затирание символов с помощью `'\b'`. Попробуйте запустить скрипт вне IDE.

Comment: в обычной консоли `cmd` все крутится

Comment: я использую мак ос, тут терминал. А не происходит ничего, просто как будто цикл while True запущен и все

Comment: @PetukhovLive, попробуйте без `'\b'` (символы просто будут печататься в одну строку, без затирания), скорее всего проблема как раз в нем.

Comment: [происхождение кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/704612/23044) (для ясности: код на моей Ubuntu машине работает в терминале).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> в терминале мак ос код работает как планировалось - вертушка крутится на одном месте, в PyCharm'е - нет

Если в терминале у вас работает, а в PyCharm нет, то включите Run -> Edit Configurations -> Python -> Configuration -> Emulate terminal in output console переключатель в PyCharm.

### [image: pycharm screencast]

`'\b'` экранирующая последовательность используется, чтобы вывести управляющий символ [«Возврат на шаг (BS: Backspace)»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B). В терминале курсор должен на одну позицию назад перейти (`BS`, `CR` могут работать даже в среде, где не поддерживаются [управляющие последовательности ANSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI)) — к примеру даже MS-DOS 1.0 поддерживала BS, а [`colorama` модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) позволяет использовать некоторые ANSI последовательности и в Windows консоли (на Линукс и Маках и так в терминале всё работает). [IDLE не поддерживает ни `\b` ни `\r`](https://bugs.python.org/issue23220).

Если вы ничего не видите, то возможны несколько вариантов. Например, всё работает, но вертушка скрыта [непрозрачным, немигающим] курсором, тогда попробуйте использовать `'\b' + c` вместо `c + '\b'` (в первом выражении символ печатается после шага назад перед паузой, тогда курсор справа от вертушки, а не на самой вертушке будет виден) -- [пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/564825/23044).

Или же GUI виджет, куда PyCharm у вас печатает, не поддерживает этот управляющий символ. Хотя я вижу [BACKSPACE явно упоминается в коде](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/execution/process/AnsiEscapeDecoder.java) (ссылка из [@yole's ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31502144/4279)). Попробуйте запустить код вне PyCharm в обычном терминале (Terminal, iTerm2, etc на macOS).

Для проверки, можно простой код использовать:

```
$ python -c "print('a\bc')"
c
```

Букву `a` вы не должны увидеть. Буква `c` поверх неё должна быть напечатана.

Comment: Проверка в терминале работает, выводится c. Действительно, если поменять местами c и \b, то выводится каждый элемент с новой строки

Comment: @PetukhovLive: Где у вас новые строки печатаются? Вы видите в коде в вопросе `end=''`? Что в терминале код из вопроса делает? (опишите курсор: моргает/не моргает, прозрачный/непрозрачный прямоугольник, как подчёркивание выглядит)

Comment: в терминале мак ос код работает как планировалось - вертушка крутится на одном месте, в PyCharm'е - нет

Comment: @PetukhovLive: тогда PyCharm настройте (я обновил ответ)

Comment: Теперь все работает , спасибо