# Почему не работает '\b' в entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

Почему при попытки вывести на `Entry '\b'` появляется чёрный кружочек вместо `backspace`?

Код:

```
if key == 'BS':
    calc_entry.insert(END, '\b')
```

[image: Вот такая картина]

Comment: Я вводил и '\b', и '\x08', 'BackSpace' ничего не помогает

Comment: А какой результат вы ожидали получить?

Comment: связанный вопрос (больше о `BS` символе) [Не работает цикл из `itertools.cycle()` использующий `\b` в PyCharm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/705235/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так это можно реализовать чуть другим способом

```
import tkinter


def backspace():
    entry_text.delete(len(entry_text.get())-1)


root = tkinter.Tk()
entry_text = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry_text.insert(0, '1234567890')
entry_text.pack()
bs = tkinter.Button(root, text='BS', command=backspace)
bs.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Это был мой запасной вариант. Я думал, что можно проще. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы удалить символ перед позицией курсора (как это клавиша <kbd>Backspace</kbd> делает), можно `'insert'` позицию использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter.ttk

root = tkinter.Tk()
entry = tkinter.ttk.Entry(width=30)
entry.insert(0, "press BS to emulate <Backspace> key")
entry.pack()
tkinter.ttk.Button(
    text="BS",
    command=lambda: entry.delete(entry.index(tkinter.INSERT) - 1)).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Всё отлично работает. Не знал о index(INSERT).

Comment: @АлександрЗавалишин index('insert') позицию курсора возвращает.