# Очистка консоли после каждого принта

Tags: python

Как после каждого вывода текста в консоль функцией print, сразу чистить выведенный текст. К примеру:

```
import time

aggr = '#'

for n in range(10):
    print(aggr * n)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Что бы после данного кода не выводило в консоль вот это:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########
#########
```

А предыдущий текст затирался, и на его месте появлялся новый, то есть должна быть одна строка которая плавно заполнится от одного # до #########. Возможно ли это и как правильно реализовать?

Comment: Вам нужно кроссплатформенно или решение, работающее только в юникс-терминалах, тоже сойдёт?

Comment: @andreymal лучше конечно кросс

Comment: А вам не прогрессбар ли нужен? Просто есть готовые решения.

Comment: @mkkik да, я его уже почти написал, вот столкнулся с тем что не знаю как поток вывода чистить, не когда не было данной потребности, а вот появилась.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Нужна ли многопоточность, чтобы показывать прогресс долговыполняющейся функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564768/23044)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388390/python-clearing-the-terminal-screen-more-elegantly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для "затирания" текста можно использовать символ возврата каретки `\r` без перевода строки:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print('*' * (i + 1), end='\r')
    time.sleep(.3)
print()
```

Но можно и не затирать, а выводить по одному символу, принудительно "выпихивая" буфер на каждой итерации цикла:

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print('#', end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(.3)
print()
```

Comment: можно print('*' * (i+1), end='\r')

Answer (score 11):

Для управления консолью обычно используют [ANSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), но Windows-консоль его не поддерживает, поэтому предварительно придётся воткнуть какой-нибудь костыль для его поддержки. Обычно устанавливают и используют модуль [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama):

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
```

Его установка и дружба с pycharm данного вопроса не касается, поэтому не буду это описывать.

---

Можно передвинуть курсор на один символ назад с помощью [ASCII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)-символа BS (escape-последовательность `\b`). После этого можно напечатать новый текст поверх старого:

```
print('abc\b\bXY')
```

Выведет: `aXY`

---

Можно передвинуть курсор в начало строки с помощью возврата каретки (`\r`) и тоже напечатать что-нибудь поверх:

```
print('abcde\r123')
```

Выведет: `123de`

---

Можно стереть все символы от курсора до конца строки с помощью ANSI-последовательности `\033[K` (для Windows нужна вышеупомянутая colorama). В примере ниже переносим курсор на четыре символа влево и тем самым стираем последнее слово:

```
print('foo bar baz\b\b\b\b\033[K!')
```

Выведет: `foo bar!` (от baz не будет и следа)

Если переместить курсор в начало строки, то можно стереть всю строку:

```
print('###############\r\033[KDone!')
```

Выведет: `Done!` (без всяких решёточек)

---

Можно передвинуть курсор на одну строку вверх и в её начало с помощью `\033[F`:

```
print('foo')
print('\033[F!')
```

Выведет: `!oo`

---

Комбинируя всё вышеперечисленное, можно модифицировать ваш пример таким образом:

```
import time

aggr = '#'

for n in range(10):
    if n > 0:
        # Если мы выводили решёточки в предыдущей итерации,
        # то поднимаемся на строку назад и стираем их
        print('\033[F\033[K', end='')
    print(aggr * n)
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

Но, возможно, для вашего частного случая намного лучше подойдёт [вариант от mkkik](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715582/178213) :)

[Больше об управляющих последовательностях ANSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI)

Comment: в моём окружении: `print("\033c")` работает, чтобы очистить экран в терминале. [Python - Clearing the terminal screen more elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34388390/4279). На Windows 10 поддерживаются напрямую (если включить) последовательности, основанные на VT100: так называемые [Console Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences)

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы не изобретать велосипед, можно использовать [`tqdm` модуль](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26394657/4279) (читается как [«такадум»](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdoZvo8j6tc) — означает «прогресс»): 
[image: tqdm console demo]

Comment: иногда под индивидуальные задачи все же приходиться изобретать велосипед

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч: если у вас есть какие-то специальные требования, которые заставляют вас думать, что tqdm не будет работать в вашем случае, то их следует явно упомянуть в вопросе.

Comment: Дело такого рода, что вопрос вообще не про прогрессбар был, а про то как поток вывода почистить, а про бар то уже в процессе переговоров в комментариях всплыло )

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч вопрос явно говорит: *"должна быть одна строка которая плавно заполнится от одного # до #########"* — это и есть progressbar. Другие ответы уже упомянули `\b`, `\r`, ANSI управляющие последовательности, colorama для кроссплатформенности — я не стал повторяться. Хотя в вашем случае вообще достаточно: `print('#', end='', flush=True)` чтобы по одному # вывести.

Comment: ну если на то пошло, вопрос стоял как очищать консоль после каждого принта, а пример с ### был приведен ниже, для более понятного описания чего хочу, и в моем случае не подойдет print('#', end='', flush=True), в моем случае подойдет именно то о чем я просил, а именно очистка консоли после каждого вывода, а ответ от mkkik, действительно хорошо вписывается в ответ на мой вопрос.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч на будущее: старайтесь примеры приводить, которые отражают суть вашего вопроса. И когда на комментарии отвечаете, то на вопрос ["А вам не прогрессбар ли нужен?"](https://goo.gl/Bo4VSi) нужно вместо  ["да, я его уже почти написал,..."](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715566/%d0%9e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0#comment1074145_715566) как вы сделали, лучше сказать для ясности "нет мне прогрессбар не нужен"

Comment: для ясности суть вопроса указана в вопросе, а в комментариях уже если человек задает вопрос то поему бы ему не ответить, суть изначально заданого вопроса это не меняет ни как. Так что если я даже ответил в комментах что для прогрессбара, это изначально заданный вопрос не трансформировало и не как не изменило.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч попробуйте посмотреть на ваш вопрос со стороны. Пример у вас в самом вопросе о прогрессбар. На *уточняющий* комментарий (чтобы прояснить о чём вопрос) вы опять таки ответили утвердительно про прогрессбар. Люди не телепаты, чтобы понять что на самом деле вы имеете в виду не то что говорите.

Comment: О каких телепатах вы говорите ? Суть вопроса была четко указана, что бы прочитать вопрос и ответить на него телепатом быть не нужно, а где я буду применять тот участок кода в програссабе или любой другой программе это уже не играет роли, и суть вопроса не как не меняет, и все все прекрасно поняли и дали нужные ответы, одному вам телепат понадобился. Не забудьте отминусть вопрос со всех аккаунтов, а то одного минуса мало.

Answer (score 2):

```
in [7]: import time

In [8]: import os

In [9]: def foo():
   ...:     aggr = '#'
   ...:     for n in range(10):
   ...:         print(aggr * n)
   ...:         time.sleep(0.3)
   ...:         os.system('cls')
```

Или так:

```
In [18]: def clearShell():
    ...:     os.system(['clear', 'cls'][os.name == os.sys.platform])
```

Comment: Не кроссплатформенно

Comment: Под линь `clear` вместо `cls`. Можно проверять ось и ставить как надо :)

Comment: Блин хотел в начале написать что решение с системной оболочкой не подходят,  из головы вылетело, system это первое что мне в голову пришло но не подходит )

Comment: Я думал что на python можно как на СИ отключить буферизацию ввода, и будет нужный эффект, если в Python это вообще возможно

Comment: os.name == os.sys.platform - это ж костылищё

Answer (score -1):

напиши в конце
print("\033[H\033[J")
это очистит консоль и будет типо анимация

Answer (score -1):

Можно так:

```
import time

for i in range(10):
    print('#', end = '')
    time.sleep(.3)
print()
```

Comment: Если вывод буферизованный, то ваш код аналогичен следующему `sleep(3); print("##########")`

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это практически один в один второй вариант из ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715582/1365, только без flush

Comment: А так, чтобы принудительный сброс буфера происходил, можно параметр flush использовать: `print('#', end = '', flush=True)`