# Python обновление текста в консоли

Tags: python

Выводится какой либо текст в несколько строк и на одной из строки меняются какие-либо символы не затрагивая соседние. Прямой пример в этом видео https://youtu.be/hfdhqjkCLck?t=87 на 1:26.

Как такое реализовано. Там идет очистка всей консоли и перезапись всего текста или же есть другие варианты?

Comment: curses вам в помощь.

Comment: @strawdog надо заметить, что он не поддерживает винду

Comment: @PavelDurmanov для винды есть windows-curses.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Очистка консоли после каждого принта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715566/%d0%9e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать с помощью возврата каретки:

```
In [4]: import time

In [5]: text = 'hello {}'

In [6]: for i in range(10):
   ...:     print(text.format(i) + '\r', end='')
   ...:     time.sleep(1)
```

`\r` возвращает курсор вначало строки и заменяет текст, пример:

```
In [10]: print('      world\rhello')
hello world
```

Мы заменили 5 пробелов вначале строки на слово `hello`.

Comment: А что если будет несколько строк, я именно для этого видео и привел пример.
text = 'hello {}\nworld {}\nhi {}'