# Как стирать с консоли вывод?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начал писать на питоне и не знаю как удалить вывод. Про `\r` (сброс каретки) я знаю.
Нужно конкретно **удалить** то что я вывел (с помощью `print`) с консоли.

Comment: Вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715566/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/715597

Comment: @MihailPy Это не то, я уже сморел

Comment: Опишите тогда вопрос получше.

Comment: Какая у Вас ОС?

Comment: Windows но это не имеет значения, т.к. я на онлайн компиляторе.

Comment: тогда нужно знать что поддерживает Ваш онлайн компилятор)

Comment: Наверо всё с языка Python 3

Comment: язык непричем. питон может сделать что угодно, а вот рисованием символов занимается терминал, а не язык.

Comment: Я не знаю что он там подерживает, но комп. такой: OnlineGDB beta

Comment: onlinegdb.com..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для прогрессбаров и однострочных бегущих фигней подходит `\r` - переход к началу строки

```
print('#'*5, end='\r')
time.sleep(1)
print('@'*2, end='\r')
```

Если нужно чтото большее - то зависит от возможностей терминала. Какая у Вас ОС?

Для виндовс cmd

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

Для нормальных терминалов можно послать управляющую последовательность

```
print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

`chr(27)` это эскейп, после которого следует команда для управления терминалов, а `"[2J"` сама команда очистить экран

для `onlinegdb.com` последний способ пойдет ( для `pythonfiddle.com` - нет)

https://onlinegdb.com/ryzeZj7vL

Comment: Да но я уже писал прогресс-бар и "прочую фигню" тут другое

Comment: Ничего не понял...

Comment: ссылку дай на онлайн терминал твой)

Comment: onlinegdb.com..