# Анимация текста python

Tags: python, python-3.x, print

Как сделать так, чтобы во время загрузки в моей программе к тексту "Загрузка" каждую секунду прибавлялось по точке, а потом они убирались (через `print`.)

Вот такой код сейчас (прога чисто по фану):

```
from time import sleep
import time
import random
import sys
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
from random import randint



init(convert=True)

ggg=(input('Вас приветствует программа hack casino vulkan!\nНапишите 1 чтобы начать, 0 чтобы пойти пойти нафиг\n'))

if ggg=='1':
    print(Back.GREEN + 'Загрузка...')  #тут
    time.sleep(randint(9, 30))
    print(Back.GREEN + 'Запуск...')  #тут
    time.sleep(randint(12, 45))

else:
    print(Back.BLUE + 'Вы идете нафиг...')
    time.sleep(3)
    print(Back.RED + 'Вы пришли нафиг! Досвидания!')
    time.sleep(3)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3160699/13970074

Comment: добавил код @Kromster

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Очистка консоли после каждого принта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715566/%d0%9e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3):

Советую вам воспользоваться данным [примером](https://habr.com/ru/post/483400/), т.к. вручную если и возможно, то слишком муторно.

### Пример

```
import time
from progress.bar import IncrementalBar

mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

bar = IncrementalBar('Countdown', max = len(mylist))

for item in mylist:
    bar.next()
    time.sleep(1)

bar.finish()
```

Comment: Не отвечайте ответами-ссылками. Постарайтесь приводить в ответе основное, а ссылку использовать лишь как дополнение.

Comment: @Kromster, исправил. Забыл что лучше так не делать

Answer (score 0):

Если попытаться сделать исключительно через метод print в некоторых консолях работать будет а в некоторых нет

```
import time
import random
import sys
from turtle import back
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
from random import randint
import os


init(convert=True)

ggg=(input('Вас приветствует программа hack casino vulkan!\nНапишите 1 чтобы начать, 0 чтобы пойти пойти нафиг\n'))

if ggg=='1':
    Time=randint(9, 30)
    Count=Time*2
    load="."
    for i in range(Count):
        os.system("cls")
        print(Back.GREEN + f'Загрузка{load}' + Back.BLACK)
        if len(load) == 3 :load=""
        load = load+"."
        time.sleep(0.5)

    Time=randint(12, 45)
    Count=Time*2
    load="."
    for i in range(Count):
        print(Back.GREEN + f'Запуск{load}' + Back.BLACK)
        load = load+"."
        if len(load) == 3 :load="."
        time.sleep(0.5)


else:
    print(Back.BLUE + 'Вы идете нафиг...')
    time.sleep(3)
    print(Back.RED + 'Вы пришли нафиг! Досвидания!')
    time.sleep(3)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]