# Можно ли как-то изменить уже отправленный текст (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

как можно после отправки текста изменить его, например: в консоль вывелось 5 и чтоб через секунду выводилось вместо 5 6 но при этом 5 пропало, но не очищать консоль, чтоб данные которые были выведенны до этого сохранились

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Очистка консоли после каждого принта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715566/%d0%9e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

делайте вот так:

```
print('test', end ='\r')
print('abcd', end ='\r')
```

`\r` переводит каретку в начале строки и можно затереть строку

Comment: к test просто дописываеться abcd, я говорил что надо ЗАМЕНИТЬ строку, а не добавить к ней что-то

Comment: @Selasi А вы где этот код пробуете?

Comment: Не понял вопрос

Comment: @Selasi Работа кода сильно зависит от того, где вы пробуете код. В командной строке запускаете скрипт, в какой-то IDE, в Jupyter Notebook - вариантов то много. Где-то будет `\r` работать, а где-то нет.

Comment: Запускал в Python Idle

Comment: @Selasi Ну вот запустите в командной строке. В оболочках не факт что будет работать, смотря как консоль там реализована