# Как можно сделать автозамену текста в консоли

Tags: python, консоль, текст

Есть код:

```
for x in range(100):
     print(x)
```

Можно в консоли менять текст для создания загрузки?

Comment: Можно использовать \r в конце строки, это возврат каретки `print('что-то там', end='\r')`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Очистка консоли после каждого принта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715566/%d0%9e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
import time

for x in range(100):
    print(f'\r{x}', end='')
    time.sleep(1) # поставил задержку, чтобы было видно процесс
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - использовать специальную библиотеку для показа прогресс-бара:

```py
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

for x in tqdm(range(100)):
     pass
```

Там можно и свою надпись ставить/менять, но удобнее пользоваться автоматической полоской прогресса.