# Как сделать анимацию времени в python?

Tags: python

Задача такая: сделать так, что бы время на python каждую секунду менялось.
Как это сделать через модуль time?
Есть такой код:

```
import time

a = time.ctime()
print("Текущее время: ", a)
```

Но он выводит текущее время, не меняя его

```
Текущее время:  Thu Oct 13 21:18:18 2022
```

Помогите чем сможете

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Где и зачем менять время?

Comment: Если же вы на самом деле не хотите ничего менять, а просто хотите выводить текущее время раз в секунду, то, очевидно, просто напишите цикл

Comment: Если я сделаю цикл, то будет выводится много строк. А как сделать, что бы строка удалялась и вместо неё показывало новое время?

Comment: [Очистка консоли после каждого принта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/715566)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import time

while True:
    a = time.ctime()
    print("Текущее время: ", a, end='\t\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1/24)
```

Comment: Да, это то что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: А зачем `\t` ?.

Comment: Для красоты. Не уверен что строка постоянной длинны. Добить "ячейку" до конца

Comment: @andreymal а ещё юзер может нажать на клавиатуре символ и сбить курсор и тогда останется хвост. Вместо \t надо `' ' *(ширина консоли- len(a)) ` или чтото такое

Comment: Может опаздывают? Если опаздывают то надо сбросить буфер.

Comment: @eri эти пробелы будет выделяться и копироваться, поэтому надо `\033[K`

Answer (score 2):

Вам что то такое нужно?

```
import time

while True:
  a = time.ctime()
  print("Текущее время: ", a, end='\r')
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Нет, выше уже помогли, но спасибо)

Comment: Я был позже на 3 минуты)

Comment: @eri  ничего страшного