# Cоздание анимации пишущей машинки c обратным процессом в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, терминал

Здравствуйте. 
Есть к примеру код, в котором уведомление о статусе выполнения функции происходит через строку. :

```
while x != 50:
    print('Searching results...')
    # выполнение функции
    x += 1
```

Как сделать анимацию точек без перехода на новую строчку ? 
Т.е сначала - `Searching results`
через `time.sleep(0.2)` - `Searching results.`
через ещё одну `time.sleep(0.2)` - `Searching results..`
И как только строчка дописывается до `Searching results...` чтоб шёл обратный процесс : 
`Searching results..`
`Searching results.`
`Searching results`
Всё это в одной строке.

Comment: [ASCII и ANSI вам в помощь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715597/178213)

Comment: И там же связанный вопрос про [показывать прогресс долговыполняющейся функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564768)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы не было переноса строки, можно передать `end=''`  в [`print()` функцию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
print('Searching', end='')
```

Чтобы назад курсор при печати перевести, можно использовать [`'\b'` («Возврат на шаг» управляющий символ)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705297/23044):

```
import itertools
import time

it = itertools.cycle(['.'] * 3 + ['\b \b'] * 3)
for x in range(30):
    time.sleep(.3)  # выполнение функции
    print(next(it), end='', flush=True)
print('\nDone.')
```

`flush=True` очищает stdout буфер, иначе на экране ничего не появится, пока буфер не заполнится или скрипт не завершится (при нормальном выходе из программы python сам очищает буфер). При выводе в терминал, стандартный вывод буферизирован построчно (stdout буфер очищается когда встречается `\n` — символ новой строки). В коде выше `\n` не выводится, поэтому приходится руками буфер сбрасывать с помощью `flush=True`.

[image: animation of tty session]

Answer (score 0):

## Метод через pyautogui

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pyautogui as pgui  # pip3 install pyautogui

for x in range(30):
    word = pgui.typewrite('Searching...', interval=.2) 
    for y in range(len('Searching...')):
        pgui.press(['backspace'], interval=.1)


print('\nDone.')
```

*Ну я и <strike>Noob Saibot</strike> молодец...*

**Внимание** : **Метод** всё же **не хороший**, ибо если свернуть программу при выполнении этой функции и к примеру если активен браузер,то *Searching...* будет выполнятся и там (в адресной строке).

Comment: Ненавижу костыли