# Обновление вывода print в Console pyCharm.Как изменить строку вывода? 10 , после обновилось на 9 и тд.?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
index = len(list)
for i in list:
   index-=1
   print(index)
```

Даёт построчный вывод

```
# 10
# 9
# 8
# 7
# 6
```

А как сделать смену в той же строчке? Чтобы 10 изменилось на 9, затем на 8 и т.д.?

Comment: Попробуйте в вопросе указать какой результат ожидается

Comment: Измените заголовок вопроса. Я же предоставил вам нормальный вариант. Возьмите, например, вариант "Как изменить строку вывода?"

Comment: связанный вопрос [Не работает цикл из itertools.cycle() использующий \b в PyCharm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/705235/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Cоздание анимации пишущей машинки c обратным процессом в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/725081/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
import time

write, flush = sys.stdout.write, sys.stdout.flush
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
index = len(list)
print(len(list))
for i in list:
    if i == 3:
        print('\r' + 'text : 3')
    index -= 1
    write('\r' + 'Left: ' + str(index))
    flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

список может быть любым, я указал длину списка, добавил условие if для наглядности затирки, а то к цифрам приписывался предыдущий print. Огромная просьба уважаемые, вы пишите свои функции , но зачастую тут вопросы оставляют новички, вписывайте ответ в вопрос. Спасибо всем.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы выполнить обратный отчёт от 10 до 1, печатая по одному числу в ту же строку, можно вывести управляющий символ [«Возврат каретки (CR: CARRIAGE RETURN)»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B)
 — `'\r'`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import time

for i in reversed(range(1, 11)):
    sys.stderr.write(f"{i:2d}\r")
    time.sleep(.5)
```

[image: tty session]

В PyCharm (включив: ["Emulate terminal in output console"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705297/23044)) это выглядит как:

[image: pycharm screencast]

Comment: а почему в `stderr`? :)

Comment: @gil9red традиционно прогресс/статус/лог в stderr печатается, а полезный вывод в stdout (для потребления процессами ниже по течению). Пример `curl`, `grep`, `find`, `pv`. [When to use STDERR instead of STDOUT](https://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766119-when-to-use-stderr-instead-of-stdout)

Comment: Понятно. Это разумно!

Comment: сможете к моему ответу ниже . написать код с использованием sys.stdout.write(f"{i:2d}\r") ?

Comment: @user284883: чем вывод кода в моём ответе от желаемого отличается? Вот вы скопировали код из моего ответа, вставили как есть в PyCharm, запустили. Что вы видите после этого  на экране? Что бы вы хотели вместо этого увидеть? Обновите ваш вопрос и подробно по шагам опишите. Если словами не получается описать или просто для ясности, картинки добавьте (хоть от руки рисуйте).

Comment: совсем ни чего не увидел, а вот если вы мой код вставите как есть в pyCharm , вам станет все понятно и видно. я  задал вопрос  , все помогли на него ответить , я сам написал ответ развернуто и кто будет пробовать мой код все поймут , а ваш нет

Comment: @user284883: *"cовсем ни чего не увидел"* — [вы на ссылку из комментария нажимали?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787253/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-print-%d0%b2-console-pycharm-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-10-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5/787279?noredirect=1#comment1238331_787253) У вас галочка, рекомендованная в ответе по ссылке стоит?

Comment: у кого работает код  "как есть " в pyCharm  ?

Answer (score 2):

Можно реализовать таким образом:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import time
>>> def f(n):
...   write, flush = sys.stdout.write, sys.stdout.flush
...   for i in range(n):
...     write(str(i))
...     flush()
...     write('\x08' * 10)
...     time.sleep(0.1)
... 
>>> f(10)
```

Comment: а можно без `>>>` и `...`? :)

Comment: `\x08` можно как `\b` записать (BS: Backspace). `write('\b'*width)` лучше после `time.sleep(0.1)` писать (`flush()`   после `write('\b')` у вас нет).

Answer (score 1):

У меня вот так получилось:

```
import sys
import time


def f(n):
    last_num_chars = 0

    write, flush = sys.stdout.write, sys.stdout.flush
    while n >= 0:
        write('\r' * last_num_chars)
        last_num_chars = write('Left: ' + str(n))
        flush()

        time.sleep(1)
        n -= 1

f(10)
```

Comment: Для ответа немного изменил старый аналогичный код: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/78b0f1a61ca667c3670f21d0e044de555242df80/gitpython_examples/cycle_commit.py#L7

Comment: Я так понял, автор хочет удалять 10 и выводить следующий элемент коллекции

Comment: Без точной поставленной задачи, сколько людей, столько и мнений :)

Comment: повторять `'\r'`  подряд не имеет смысла. Если CR работает, то курсор в начало строки помещается¶ `\r` не затирает строку, поэтому у вас цифры от предыдущих чисел могут остаться (поэтому в моём ответе `{:2d}` format используется

Comment: @jfs, теперь понятно, почему ваш код не работает в консоли пичарма, в отличии от консоли ОС :)

Comment: @gil9red: мой код работает как в консоли так и в pycharm. Можно на движущиеся картинки посмотреть в ответе.

Comment: @jfs, я включил тот флаг, запустил и у меня просто на каждой строке стала печататься следующая цифра. Без включения флага (такое по умолчанию было) в консоли пичарма ничего не было написано

Comment: @gil9red: если вы о моём коде говорите, то вероятно лучше под моим ответом комментарий оставить и если вы не думаете, что я в фотошопе screencast нарисовал, то имеет смысл какие-нибудь подробности упомянуть о вашем окружении (так как в моём окружении, pycharm очевидно работает): OS, версия pycharm, переменные окружения (единственное изменение от настроек по умолчанию у меня это флаг "Emulate terminal in output console", который я явно в ответе упомянул, а по ссылке в комментарии ещё до публикации ответа было описано решение)¶ В любом случае, если у вас \r не работает, то и `'\r'*10` не поможет

Comment: @jfs, win7, PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.3, PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

Answer (score 0):

Так что-ли?

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

index = len(list)-1
for i in list:
    index-=1
    print(index)
# 9
# 8
# 7
# 6
# ...
# -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идёт об одной строке...

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for i in lst:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Comment: обновление строки вывода