# Вывод счетчика итераций в командную строку. Python

Tags: python, интерфейс, вывод

В моей программе пользователь вводит алгоритм и строку, на которой этот алгоритм должен быть применен. Т.к работа этого алгоритма может включать очень много итераций, то я хочу добавить *"счетчик итераций"*, который будет показывать пользователю, что программа не зависла, а продолжает работать.

Программа работает в командной строке, соответственно счетчик я хочу выводить именно туда. По задумке строка счетчика должна выглядеть так:

```
Количество итераций: ()
```

Где на месте скобок постоянно обновляющееся число итераций алгоритма.

Переменная, которая отображает кол-во итераций у меня уже заведена, остается только вопрос как отображать это. Подскажите, с помощью каких инструментов это можно реализовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834311/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Вот тут посмотри https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787253/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-print-%D0%B2-console-pycharm-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-10-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5

Comment: В чем именно заключается вопрос? Как считать итерации автоматически или как выводить (принтовать)?

Comment: `print(f'\rКоличество итераций: ({it_count})', end='')`

Comment: А вообще не выдумывайте велосипед после автомобиля. Есть отличный прогрессбар `tqdm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспроизводимый пример для комментария к посту:

```py
import time

for it_count in range(10):
    print(f'\rКоличество итераций: ({it_count})', end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Та же самая задача через `tqdm`

```py
import time
import tqdm

for it_count in tqdm.tqdm(range(10)):
    time.sleep(1)

#  90%|█████████ | 9/10 [00:09<00:01,  1.00s/it]
```