# Как сделать бесконечно меняющиеся символы?

Tags: python, строки, случайные-числа

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать бесконечно меняющийся текст, который заменяет свои символы на другие, и так вечно?

Примерно так, jdkjkejfwoj и через секунду этот же текст меняется на другой рандомный

Есть код, но он просто выводит рандомные символы

```
import string

output_string = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(20))

print(output_string)
```

Comment: А чем не устранивает рандом, это ведь так же бесконечно разнвые символы?

Comment: Они же не меняются постоянно, а только при каждом запуске кода вроде

Comment: Используйте бесконечный цикл while

Comment: Поставьте условие которое никогда не достигнется

Comment: Цикл while True:. Внутри цикла делаешь вот такую штуку: https://question-it.com/questions/1488719/v-python-kak-izmenit-tekst-posle-ego-pechati или вот так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787253/Обновление-вывода-print-в-console-pycharm-Как-изменить-строку-вывода-10-после

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня работает вот так:

```
import sys
import time
import string
import random


def f():
    write, flush = sys.stdout.write, sys.stdout.flush
    while True:
        last_num_chars = write(''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
                                       for _ in range(20)))
        write('\r' * last_num_chars)
        flush()

        time.sleep(1)


f()
```

Чтобы заработало в pycharm если надо поставить галочку: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705235/Не-работает-цикл-из-itertools-cycle-использующий-b-в-pycharm/705297#705297](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/705235/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%B7-itertools-cycle-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-b-%D0%B2-pycharm/705297#705297)

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает